# MongoDB Atlas - waiting 20 hours for server to be recovered / healthy? Anything I can do?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

[image]

[image]

Our MongoDB Atlas project has been in this state `deploying your changes: 1 of 3 servers complete...` for 20 hours now. We believe the issue was caused by one or more of (a) inserting too much data too quickly into our cluster, and (b) attempting to create compound indexes using fields that did not appear in the data. We've messaged `MongoDB Atlas` for help, but they take off weekends.

In general, we are wondering if there is anything we can do to resolve this issue from the MongoDB Atlas UI without their support? Can we restart the problematic replicaset node somehow?

**Edit:** all index-building is hanging, stuck at 0% even for simple indexes. Not great...

[image]